# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Storage' with Google Analytics API

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've built a Google Analytics API that pulls a number or dimensions and metrics from multiple GA views within separate accounts. My code essentially cycles through an excel document and determines what view to select and uses the corresponding .dat file credentials it needs from a dictionary. The weird thing is it works for the first view in the document but then fails once it gets to the next one no matter what is listed in that row. I keep getting the error message...

***storage = file.Storage(stor_str)***

**AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Storage'**

Here is hopefully the relevant pieces of my code for reference (please let me know if I'm missing anything)...

```
lz = zip(LI, DN, VI, V, DA, S, D)
sd = '2020-08-01'
ed = '2020-08-31'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
flags = parser.parse_args([])

flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
     CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
     message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

dFI = {'DP7': 'arsseven.dat',
       'DP6': 'arssix.dat',
       'DP4': 'arsfour.dat',
       'DP0': 'arszero.dat'}

gaDO = []

def getGADO(VI, sd, ed):
    l = vi_start + str(int(VI))
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(
            body={
            'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': l,
                'dateRanges': [{'sd': sd, 'ed': ed}],
                'metrics': [
                    {'expression': 'ga:users'},
                    {'expression': 'ga:avgSessionDuration'}
                    ],
                'dimensions': [
                    {'name': 'ga:channelGrouping'}
                    ]
            }]}).execute()
    report_list = response.get('reports')
    for report in report_list:
        data_rows = report.get('data', {}).get('rows', [])
        for row in data_rows:
            dimensions_in_row = row.get('dimensions')
            metrics_rows = row.get('metrics')
            for metrics in metrics_rows:
                metrics_values = metrics.get('values')
                full_row_data = dimensions_in_row + metrics_values
                gaDO.append(full_row_data)

    gaDON = []
    for i in gaDO:
        new_tuple = []
        new_tuple.append(i[0])
        new_tuple.append(int(i[1]))
        new_tuple.append(float(i[2]))
        gaDON.append(tuple(new_tuple))

    colO = [
    #Dimensions
    'DCG',
    #Metrics
    'Users', 'ASD']
    dfO = pd.DataFrame(gaDON, columns = colO)
    print(dfO)
    return dfO

for LI, DN, VI, V, DA, S, D in locations_zip:
    dID_str = str(int(LI))
    stor_str = dFI[DA]
    storage = file.Storage(stor_str)
    credentials = storage.get()
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
    http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
    analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)
    vi_start = 'ga:'
    dfX = getGADO(VI, sd, ed)
    print(dfX)
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Comment: What is `file` and where is it defined? The error message is saying that `file` is a string, is this supposed to be some other type of object created from a filename string?

Comment: @mattficke - Ugh I'm such an idiot! I had an old variable named "file" with a directory path deep in the loop that wasn't changed/commented out so it was picking that up that the second time through. Thank you so much for your help!